# In-memory open-cv image visualization on eclipse

Tags: eclipse, visual-studio, debugging, opencv, computer-vision

There is a Visual Studio [plug in](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/redmond/groups/ivm/imagewatchhelp/imagewatchhelp.htm) that allows you to visualize images load into memory while debugging an application written on OpenCV (and even other libraries).

**Is there a way to do the same on Eclipse (and Linux if that makes a difference)?**

I'm trying to avoid touching the code, creating windows to display images or writing them to disk.